# Regex replace or add substring in Python

Tags: python, regex, replace

I need a unique regex to replace a substring or add it if missing.

Example:

```
set beta=10
"alpha=25 beta=42 delta=43" need to become "alpha=25 beta=10 delta=43"
"alpha=25 delta=43" need to become "alpha=25 delta=43 beta=10"
```

This following code is functional only to replace existing value, but if the index to replace does not already exist it does not add anything.

```
dest = re.sub(r'(.*)(beta=\d+)( .*)',r'\1 beta=10 \3',source)
```

I can do that, but I need this result in one expression:

```
if re.search(r'beta=\d+',source):
    dest = re.sub(r'(.*)(beta=\d+)( .*)',r'\1 beta=10 \3',source)
else:
    dest = source + " beta=10"
```

So if beta=xx exist in a string and it doesn't match beta=yy then replace

So if beta=xx does not exist in a string then append beta=yy to string

Comment: are `alpha` `beta` `delta` te only possible entries or there could be also `gamma` `eta` ...? Are input strings in order I mean do you have always `alpha= beta=  delta= ` or might you have `beta= alpha=...`?

Comment: Can you have anything else between `alpha` and `delta`? Is `delta` always present? Is `alpha` always present?

Comment: So if beta=xx exist in a string and it doesn't match beta=yy replace?

Comment: So if beta=xx does not exist in a string append beta=yy to string?

Comment: Yes, we can have any text before or after the label I have to update. 

"Life is complex" , to yours questions, the response is yes to both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that beta=10 is only present 0 or 1 times in the string, you could do it like this:

```
dest = re.sub("(beta=\d+|$)","beta=10",source+" ",1).strip()
```

The pattern considers the end of line to be an alternative match for beta=\d+ and, since we're only substituting the first occurrence, it will only apply when the line does not contain beta=\d+